# gRPC простой пример сервера и клиента

Tags: c#, grpc

Проект учебный. Нужно написать клиент и сервер, которые бы общались посредством использования gRPC. Прочитал уже много статей, но даже не понимаю, с чего начать. С сокетами и очередями сообщений, которые в этом проекте используются, хотя бы внятные руководства с банальными примерами были, а тут прямо совсем беда. Прошу просто привести наипростейший пример клиента и сервера. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а вот это пример Вам не подойдёт? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Эм, вы серьезно? Написал в гугле `c# gRPC` и сразу выдало [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDRZM.png), ну и как бы вон вам и от Microsoft [статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start), и самого gRPC [документация](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/quickstart/), да даже [метанит](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/32.1.php) есть. И что, хотите сказать это не внятные руководства? Прям вот беда? Или всеж не искали...?

Comment: Совсем, видимо, за дурака меня держите. Как минимум, статьи с MSDN я находил. Но я просто не совсем понимаю сути того же .proto-файла.

Comment: ну тогда стоит задавать более конкретный вопрос, видимо.

Comment: Опять же, вбиваете в поисковик "proto file" и в первых же ссылках получаете описание, что это такое. Это файл для описания передаваемых данных в формате [Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers). gRPC основан именно на этом двоичном формате.

Comment: Сейчас вас вопрос слишком общий. Разбейте его на части и задавайте более мелкие конкретные вопросы. Например: "Что такое .proto-файл? Как мне написать этот файл для моих данных?" (при этом обязательно указать, какие именно данные собираетесь передавать)

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку magicOnion, она избавляет от .proto

Comment: @4per да уже разобрался, спасибо