# Сделать сервер gRPC с использованием .NET Framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, .net-5

Имеется проект на базе .NET Framework 4.7.2. Появился вопрос: возможно ли на базе этого сделать сервер и клиент gRPC (желательно, ещё включить шифрование). Пример, который кочует из статьи в статью, основан на ASP.NET Core, что для меня не очень подходит. Насчет перевода проекта с .NET Framework 4.7.2 на .NET 5.0 тоже думал, но есть сомнения в том плане, что внутри проекта также используются TCP-сокеты и очередь сообщений RabbitMQ. Есть сомнения, что оно заработает нормально.

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1329903/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переводите на .NET 5, а точнее на .NET 6 уже пора, в ноябре он выйдет в релиз. При том .NET 6 это LTS, потому большие проекты корпоративного сегмента лучше переводить сразу на него.

С TCP сокетами и AMQP в .NET 6 всё хорошо, я бы сказал даже лучше, как минимум потому что разработчики дотнета добавили сокетам новых асинхронных методов, позволяющих выкинуть кучу костылей из своего кода и работать с сокетами на низком уровне так, как удобно.

Framework уже всё: во-первых, он сравнительно медленный, во-вторых перекостыливать современные технологии на старый фреймворк ради того чтобы потом возвращать всё в зад - такое себе занятие, пустая трата времени.

Если вы привязаны к 4.7.2, я рекомендую вам отказаться от gRPC до тех пор, пока не мигрируете проект.

Еще один немаловажный нюанс. gRPC требует HTTP/2, но его поддержки в .NET Framework 4.x нет, и не предвидится.

Comment: Да проект учебный, мигрировать не проблема. Просто были сомнения по этому поводу.